# Jenkins subversion - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure SVN repository for one of my Jenkin target. But when trying to connect svn repository with https protocol and username/password

```
FAILED: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /svn/BSS_CORE_SYSTEMS/ATG/branches/Release_1_1_MASTERLIB failed
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1492)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1361)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:229)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:166)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:101)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:389)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/BSS_CORE_SYSTEMS/ATG/branches/Release_1_1_MASTERLIB'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:642)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/BSS_CORE_SYSTEMS/ATG/branches/Release_1_1_MASTERLIB'
svn: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:644)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:285)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your SVN server is using encryption cipher suites that Java has removed support for. Over time [Java has removed support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html) for weaker encryption methods for security reasons.

Your best bet, if you can, is to upgrade your subversion server's encryption protocols. Moving to TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 should fix the issue.

If you can't do that, you'll need to adjust the security policy of the JVM running Jenkins to allow insecure encryption protocols by editing your `java.security` file and adjusting this line to remove the suite your SVN server needs:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40, 3DES_EDE_CBC
```

If you need to figure out which cipher suites your SVN server supports [check out this answer over on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/224263/918678).

Comment: Thanks Michael,   I will not be able to update the SVN server but I can try updating the jenkins but not sure how can i pass the values while starting the jenkins as I am using jenkins.war file and restarting using java like 
java -jar jenkins.war